# What are those red lines with dots in RStudio editor

Tags: import, rstudio, r-haven

When importing data from SPSS with `haven`'s `read_sav` I get some `values` like `"1.     Tout à fait d?accord"` or `"2.     Plutôtd?accord"`.
Those values seem to have whitespaces between the period and the text, however, they are not actually "normal" whitespaces, as they can't be referenced using them (i.e. `%>% filter(values ==  "1.     Tout à fait d?accord")`) won't work.

A friend told me that opening the data in STATA and then copying the lines to RStudio editor produced these weird red characters (shown in image), and the code now works. How can I read these data in R adequately without going through STATA?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that these have 4 white spaces? It is quite likely that the data has `tab` as spaces which is different.
When you write into a text editor:

```
"I'm    tab    separated"
```

Then copy it to the console to assign it in R:

```
TestString <- "I'm    tab    separated"
```

To test whether it is the same as 4 white spaces we can run the following test.

```
# With 4 white spaces
TestString == "I'm    tab    separated"
[1] FALSE
```

```
# Tab separated
TestString == "I'm\ttab\tseparated"
[1] TRUE
```

By knowing this you can either replace the tab in the file or just address it during the subsetting (which is probably better).

Comment: The test works, and they are tabs indeed! But how can i detect them within R, or prevent them from importing that way from SPSS. Red lines only appear when pasting from text editor, but nor when printing i.e. the levels or unique values of a variable, which makes it very hard to detect.

Comment: Could you replace the tabs on a by column basis or is the data set also including tabs which you want to keep? If that is a possibility you could use `gsub(pattern = "\t", replacement = " ", x = x)`.

Comment: Sure, that works, but a question remains. How can I identify them in R if I do not know in advance that SPSS data has tabs?. After importing I am only able to see "whitespaces" when printing/pasting data.

Comment: You can run the mentioned `gsub` command to preemptively replace them with white space if they exist. If you just want to know whether there are tabs you can run `any(grepl(pattern = "\t", x = x))` on your columns. This will return columns which have tab. You could do this with `apply`, `data.table` or a `tidyverse` way (which I don't use so much).